# Opening files after download other than using webview

Tags: iphone, preview, qlpreviewcontroller

Is it possible to open word, excel, PDF, images file in iPhone version less than 4.0 with out using UIwebview ?. I have tried loading in web-view and here i want to know if any alternate solution to preview other than Web-view. I am downloading files from server. To preview it i dint get a proper solution which support all versions of iPhone. From iPhone 4.0 i guess qlframework can be used what about versions less than that. can some one give me clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at UIDocumentInteractionController and the Quick Look Framework to see if it can be used for your purposes.